# .NET RDLC and multiple parameters not working

Tags: stored-procedures, rdlc

I have a report that takes two parameters from a couple of text boxes that always ends up being null when passed to the stored proc. Here is the code. Also I stepped through the code and the passed in parameters have values but between passing in the params to when the proc is executed it becomes null.

```
        protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnlRecords.Visible = true;

            ReportParameter p1 = new ReportParameter("DateStart", ReportDates1.DateStart);
            ReportParameter p2 = new ReportParameter("DateEnd", ReportDates1.DateEnd);

            this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p1, p2 });
            this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        }
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is what I was missing in the .cs file

```
ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = ReportDates1.DateStart;
ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters[1].DefaultValue = ReportDates1.DateEnd;
ObjectDataSource1.DataBind();
```